# Converting string to list with dictionaries

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a big string in the following format (100K+ lines):

```
----------- Phone Information -----------

#TotalPhones, #TotalRegistered, #RegisteredSCCP, #RegisteredSIP, #UnRegistered, #Rejected, #PartiallyRegistered, StateId, #ExpUnreg
202, 202, 178, 24, 0, 0, 0, 842,0

DeviceName, Descr, Ipaddr, Ipv6addr, Ipv4Attr, Ipv6Attr, MACaddr, RegStatus, PhoneProtocol, DeviceModel, HTTPsupport, #regAttempts, prodId, username, seq#, RegStatusChg TimeStamp, IpAddrType, LoadId, ActiveLoadId, InactiveLoadId, ReqLoadId, DnldServer, DnldStatus, DnldFailReason, LastActTimeStamp, Perfmon Object
SEP001E7A24E0EE, SEP001E7A24E0EE, 10.131.96.20, , 3, 0, 001E7A24E0EE, reg, SCCP, 115, yes, 0, 115, 53131, 1, 1688637575, 1, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, , , , 0, , 1688637575, 2
SEP0014F252F8C7, SEP0014F252F8C7, 10.129.4.20, , 0, 0, 0014F252F8C7, reg, SCCP, 30007, yes, 0, 30022, 24419, 2, 1692294899, 1, CP7912080004SCCP080108A, , , , , 0, , 1692294899, 2
SEP0012D9D6A17F, SEP0012D9D6A17F, 10.142.4.20, , 0, 0, 0012D9D6A17F, reg, SCCP, 7, yes, 0, 35, 24052, 203, 1694066462, 1, P0030801SR02, , , , , 0, , 1694066462, 2
SEP0014F29CDF41, SEP0014F29CDF41, 10.129.6.2, , 0, 0, 0014F29CDF41, reg, SCCP, 30007, yes, 0, 30022, 24430, 4, 1692294885, 1, CP7912080004SCCP080108A, , , , , 0, , 1692294885, 2
SEP000D285E94F3, SEP000D285E94F3, 10.144.96.33, , 0, 0, 000D285E94F3, reg, SCCP, 8, yes, 0, 36, ANJO, 5, 1688352492, 1, P0030801SR02, , , , , 0, , 1688352492, 2
SEP001469BC6AF4, SEP001469BC6AF4, 10.129.4.24, , 0, 0, 001469BC6AF4, reg, SCCP, 7, yes, 0, 35, stvdil, 6, 1693204667, 1, P0030801SR02, , , , , 0, , 1693204667, 2
SEPEC44761E9DAB, SEPEC44761E9DAB, 10.101.6.0, , 3, 0, EC44761E9DAB, reg, SCCP, 369, yes, 0, 268, mgsst, 7, 1688352492, 1, SCCP11.9-4-2SR3-1S, SCCP11.9-4-2SR3-1S, , , , 0, , 1688352492, 2
SEP00141CDBB7C8, SEP00141CDBB7C8, 10.142.6.7, , 0, 0, 00141CDBB7C8, reg, SCCP, 30007, yes, 0, 30022, 24079, 8, 1688352492, 1, CP7912080004SCCP080108A, , , , , 0, , 1688352492, 2
SEP001AA2460268, SEP001AA2460268, 10.120.6.5, , 3, 0, 001AA2460268, reg, SCCP, 30018, yes, 0, 30044, ASGBN, 9, 1693911319, 1, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, , , , 0, , 1693911319, 2
SEP0022555E8182, SEP0022555E8182, 10.124.6.23, , 3, 0, 0022555E8182, reg, SCCP, 30018, yes, 0, 30044, 24301, 10, 1688352492, 1, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, , , , 0, , 1688352492, 2
SEP0012D9B94F83, SEP0012D9B94F83, 10.142.6.8, , 0, 0, 0012D9B94F83, reg, SCCP, 7, yes, 0, 35, NoUserId, 11, 1694169703, 1, P0030801SR02, , , , , 0, , 1694169703, 2
SEP00141C222E29, SEP00141C222E29, 10.142.6.13, , 0, 0, 00141C222E29, reg, SCCP, 30007, yes, 0, 30022, 24085, 13, 1690930229, 1, CP7912080004SCCP080108A, , , , , 0, , 1690930229, 2


----------------
Total count 202
----------------
```

I want to build a list with dictionaries that takes each headline and adds each value with the headline as the key, example (first line):

```
[
    {
        "DeviceName":"SEP001E7A24E0EE",
        "Descr":"SEP001E7A24E0EE",
        "Ipaddr":"10.131.96.20",
        "Ipv6addr":None,
        "Ipv4Attr":3,
        "Ipv6Attr":0,
        "MACaddr":"001E7A24E0EE",
        "RegStatus":"reg",
        "PhoneProtocol":"SCCP",
        "DeviceModel":115,
        "HTTPsupport":"yes",
        "#regAttempts":0,
        "prodId":115,
        "username":53131,
        "seq#":1,
        "RegStatusChg TimeStamp":1688637575,
        "IpAddrType":1,
        "LoadId":"SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S",
        "ActiveLoadId":"SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S",
        "InactiveLoadId":None,
        "ReqLoadId":None,
        "DnldServer":None,
        "DnldStatus":0,
        "DnldFailReason":None,
        "LastActTimeStamp":1688637575,
        "Perfmon Object":2
    }
]
```

What have I tried (copy/paste)?

```
test = """----------- Phone Information -----------

#TotalPhones, #TotalRegistered, #RegisteredSCCP, #RegisteredSIP, #UnRegistered, #Rejected, #PartiallyRegistered, StateId, #ExpUnreg
202, 202, 178, 24, 0, 0, 0, 842,0

DeviceName, Descr, Ipaddr, Ipv6addr, Ipv4Attr, Ipv6Attr, MACaddr, RegStatus, PhoneProtocol, DeviceModel, HTTPsupport, #regAttempts, prodId, username, seq#, RegStatusChg TimeStamp, IpAddrType, LoadId, ActiveLoadId, InactiveLoadId, ReqLoadId, DnldServer, DnldStatus, DnldFailReason, LastActTimeStamp, Perfmon Object
SEP001E7A24E0EE, SEP001E7A24E0EE, 10.131.96.20, , 3, 0, 001E7A24E0EE, reg, SCCP, 115, yes, 0, 115, 53131, 1, 1688637575, 1, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, , , , 0, , 1688637575, 2
SEP0014F252F8C7, SEP0014F252F8C7, 10.129.4.20, , 0, 0, 0014F252F8C7, reg, SCCP, 30007, yes, 0, 30022, 24419, 2, 1692294899, 1, CP7912080004SCCP080108A, , , , , 0, , 1692294899, 2
SEP0012D9D6A17F, SEP0012D9D6A17F, 10.142.4.20, , 0, 0, 0012D9D6A17F, reg, SCCP, 7, yes, 0, 35, 24052, 203, 1694066462, 1, P0030801SR02, , , , , 0, , 1694066462, 2
SEP0014F29CDF41, SEP0014F29CDF41, 10.129.6.2, , 0, 0, 0014F29CDF41, reg, SCCP, 30007, yes, 0, 30022, 24430, 4, 1692294885, 1, CP7912080004SCCP080108A, , , , , 0, , 1692294885, 2
SEP000D285E94F3, SEP000D285E94F3, 10.144.96.33, , 0, 0, 000D285E94F3, reg, SCCP, 8, yes, 0, 36, ANJO, 5, 1688352492, 1, P0030801SR02, , , , , 0, , 1688352492, 2
SEP001469BC6AF4, SEP001469BC6AF4, 10.129.4.24, , 0, 0, 001469BC6AF4, reg, SCCP, 7, yes, 0, 35, stvdil, 6, 1693204667, 1, P0030801SR02, , , , , 0, , 1693204667, 2
SEPEC44761E9DAB, SEPEC44761E9DAB, 10.101.6.0, , 3, 0, EC44761E9DAB, reg, SCCP, 369, yes, 0, 268, mgsst, 7, 1688352492, 1, SCCP11.9-4-2SR3-1S, SCCP11.9-4-2SR3-1S, , , , 0, , 1688352492, 2
SEP00141CDBB7C8, SEP00141CDBB7C8, 10.142.6.7, , 0, 0, 00141CDBB7C8, reg, SCCP, 30007, yes, 0, 30022, 24079, 8, 1688352492, 1, CP7912080004SCCP080108A, , , , , 0, , 1688352492, 2
SEP001AA2460268, SEP001AA2460268, 10.120.6.5, , 3, 0, 001AA2460268, reg, SCCP, 30018, yes, 0, 30044, ASGBN, 9, 1693911319, 1, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, , , , 0, , 1693911319, 2
SEP0022555E8182, SEP0022555E8182, 10.124.6.23, , 3, 0, 0022555E8182, reg, SCCP, 30018, yes, 0, 30044, 24301, 10, 1688352492, 1, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S, , , , 0, , 1688352492, 2
SEP0012D9B94F83, SEP0012D9B94F83, 10.142.6.8, , 0, 0, 0012D9B94F83, reg, SCCP, 7, yes, 0, 35, NoUserId, 11, 1694169703, 1, P0030801SR02, , , , , 0, , 1694169703, 2
SEP00141C222E29, SEP00141C222E29, 10.142.6.13, , 0, 0, 00141C222E29, reg, SCCP, 30007, yes, 0, 30022, 24085, 13, 1690930229, 1, CP7912080004SCCP080108A, , , , , 0, , 1690930229, 2


----------------
Total count 202
----------------"""
headlines = [x.strip().split(", ") for x in test.splitlines() if x.startswith("DeviceName")][0]
data = [{headlines[index]:word} for line in test.splitlines() for index, word in enumerate(line.strip().split(", ")) if line.startswith("SEP")]
print(data)
```

But unfortunately it gives this result:

```
[{'DeviceName': 'SEP001E7A24E0EE'}, {'Descr': 'SEP001E7A24E0EE'}, {'Ipaddr': '10.131.96.20'}, ...]
```

Can someone give some hints or maybe share a better or easier way?

I must have overseen something simple.

Comment: Strip the first and last lines and use `csv` for the main part?

Comment: I guess that's an option to go for, can you give an example? :) I'll gladly take any help I can get now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tobias_k's answer works but requires a lot of post-processing.

You can use the `skipinitialspace` option to allow `csv.DictReader` to skip spaces after each comma delimiter, use `itertools.islice` to skip the first 5 lines, and use `itertools.takewhile` with the `str.strip` method as a predicate to stop iterating upon a blank line:

```
from csv import DictReader
from io import StringIO
from itertools import islice, takewhile

file = StringIO(test)
print(list(DictReader(takewhile(str.strip, islice(file, 5, None)), skipinitialspace=True)))
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVbbcuI4EH33V7gyL6TKUJIsX/QwD8Y2u2ztECqQD/CCQjwDtscW7ObrMy35JpvMDhMCQd06ah2OWu0uXsVLntl@Ub69CV4J87N5d3c37V/mGua5ucye8/KUiDTPTG3WMD5tc5EcFaiyzNp65Ie0Erzke/D0xiYM10PHUtpP2Qj/le@EGq6TUqTJ8fiqAzYiEXwpp@P/iqes5AeDIGKZ6h/2fBhRy0Tt26fEQoYR8Uu646vkxC0z4tWutMxlkez36vvidiMaCNH46tGXIKwngYPc@gy/Uv3adZmLfJcfZTwZ@0u@52D8ud2uq3NR5KUAisAOwvBTIWBZUeZ7Sfxc8TJTTCr@/ZMWOXw5mNv0xME6FZJEADtvXwtA/p0nam2wE@mFt9YySwb2I//eDqPsuN/w8sLLZtxwl@NFksIZJVWeQeCkEhBU23bNy@cTHPPDP/IgjE28RgjHXkBojOIYDmDswGiGbTxj7oyA4JZp19oPMCAErFQJgLFjma8yW1BjODashzG8Xd93bc/xHGXKBRQiT@mUbB7tKd6876v/1OZ6BNKQpwvikIUfei15zSHJEzajDXfUctcgGncbIeT17MEkMvUoxQy@5O6MEEZ9xhT/cO0xTJAPq6gMACOM/KAl3FHuF7WUScQiN8DeoqWsOSRlSq4paxCNsk5XakKRo26LrTamyHWpSxRb2MaWDDeP8iqNKXZITVUWRguKNVVbR6MqZMRY1BZxi6g2WLTXx3c@IKrf5wGKiO/EjC7shrHuUKJSmcS2rXPWMRpnX@PrwrVc/fUAeVynn@0Qym6QtEd2krpsHrrBgnaS9o4@UelQ0x7y81OvxGWfQnVylTA2QdR1vRsOvUMqhnFIqefimEXBXDEcOiRDhOHQtSowROiH7rKeInFBz9OhqoRiPhJRLsDvVAH8/1XgSlwcRvO5F/qduL2juVLuzBtq2yNuyFfkMZUYI/q35us14wDKp4uUOFcOlQ4IGDuDkqshhoyxP2BMIV2CzR/zlWWy@qQZhiLMPl52@wgNfUIcx4l97JOGvu5Q9KksELbOX4f8kj@BAqFqzbsZ84Hnxlh/KKhzuPm@rRXh1tFljD@uwS3i57dxlT9BCyCf0hjXtRU@nqrIv6zCLVLLakJITJiW1a2j44jtcVq3kFvSWtXd@nGBmA3e33y4dYuIYRjT0ctQHaO5y8@ZkD3cFQDaUcN4LvOTuasuZnqSnZUZpTsBHcyel/VUmrczG1Gm2WH50PihaRR5fqza6bQ6Qq9mmSL5xv99SY@8xhUFrBItqLZgV5iHhrgNOZEN8r1Rz06O0JFOeh6TLuKkEuUMPin0UvV2ExlIPR5W0Dje30M9/pYWaZbK7rYqkh3/vC3PMHH/9vYD)

Answer (score 2):

Your data looks more-or-less like CSV data with some additional header and footer info, so I'd suggest using the CSV module. This will also take care of e.g. spaces or commas that are part of the actual values (provided that it actually *is* CSV and those are escaped accordingly). You can skip the first few lines, then read the rest using a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and stop as soon as you encounter the final "---" lines.

```
import csv

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for i in range(5):
        next(f) # skip header

    data = []
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    for line in reader:
        if line["DeviceName"].startswith("---"):
            break  # stop on footer
        data.append({k: v or None for k, v in line.items()})

    print(data)
```

A bit of post-processing is still necessary for converting empty strings to `None`.

Comment: I think you've helped me before with your csv magic, this looks good also.

Comment: "Unfortunately, CSV only allows for one-char delimiters (so not ', ')". That's what the [`skipinitialspace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) option is for.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks, wasn't aware of that. There is no empty-string-to-none option though, right?

Answer (score 1):

Being direct and concise, maybe you could use this:

```
test_lines = test.splitlines()
headlines = [x.strip() for x in test_lines if x.startswith("DeviceName")][0].split(", ")

data = [{headlines[index]: (None if val == '' else val) for index, val in enumerate(line.strip().split(", "))} for line in test_lines if line.startswith("SEP")]
```

Remember to handle fields without values in your csv.

Comment: This certainly looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
data = [{headlines[index]:(None if word=='' else word)  for index, word in enumerate(line.strip().split(", ")) if line.startswith("SEP")} for line in test.splitlines()]
```

you are indexing through the line outside of the dictionary, instead of inside it.

gave me something like this:

```
[
{
'DeviceName': 'SEP001E7A24E0EE'. 'Descr': 'SEP001E7A24E0EE'.
 'Ipaddr': '10.131.96.20'.
 'Ipv6addr': ''.
 'Ipv4Attr': '3'.
 'Ipv6Attr': '0'.
 'MACaddr': '001E7A24E0EE'.
 'RegStatus': 'reg'.
 'PhoneProtocol': 'SCCP'.
 'DeviceModel': '115'.
 'HTTPsupport': 'yes'.
 '#regAttempts': '0'.
 'prodId': '115'.
 'username': '53131'.
 'seq#': '1'.
 'RegStatusChg TimeStamp': '1688637575'.
 'IpAddrType': '1'.
 'LoadId': 'SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S'.
 'ActiveLoadId': 'SCCP41.9-4-2SR3-1S'.
 'InactiveLoadId': ''.
 'ReqLoadId': ''.
 'DnldServer': ''.
 'DnldStatus': '0'.
 'DnldFailReason': ''.
 'LastActTimeStamp': '1688637575'.
 'Perfmon Object': '2'
}
]
```

Comment: But this does not take into account, that empty values should be `None`. I understand the approach though and with a small change it's fixed.

Comment: try ```data = [{headlines[index]:(None if word=='' else word)  for index, word in enumerate(line.strip().split(", ")) if line.startswith("SEP")} for line in test.splitlines()]```.

Comment: You should update the answer with this.

Comment: updated, but as said elsewhere, import it as a csv

Answer (score 1):

Save the string without the header and footers to a csv file, say 'file.csv'. Then use pandas, this should result in what you want:

```py
import pandas as pd 
records = pd.read_csv('file.csv',na_values= ' ').to_dict(orient='records')
```

Edit: if you want none values to be 'None' instead of 'np.nan' use this instead :

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
records = pd.read_csv('file.csv',na_values= ' ').replace({np.nan:None}).to_dict(orient='records')
```